# Are there any out of the box Sharepoint 2010 webparts that offer paging and rollup functionality?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently working on a project with a very tight budget, and one of the page layouts requires a standard rollup of news items from a list. I've done some googling around Content Query Web Part and the new XML List View Web Part, but neither seem to have any pagination options of any kind.

Does anyone have any ideas, recommendations or thoughts as to which web part would be the most suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like List View Web Part does offer pagination, as does the Data View Web Part.